# Lebesgue Integrable Function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

My professor posed a question to us last week about the limit of a function as $k \to \infty$.  He asked us to prove that $\int \lim_{k \to \infty} f(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{k}} dx = \int f(x)dx$.  This seems fairly basic, since it can be directly shown that the exponential part of the integrand, $e^{-\frac{x^2}{k}} \to 1$ as $k \to \infty$.  Is there something I am missing?  Are there extra steps needed to show that the integral of the limit is equal to the limit of the integral?  Is this even necessary?  I feel like this question is too simple relative to the rest of the material in class, but I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: well, $f=g$ implies $\int f=\int g$...

Comment: Are you sure he didn't ask $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\int f(x)e^{-x^2/k}\,dx$?  In that case, you need to justify switching the integral and the limit.

Answer (score 3):

Over an interval or compact set,  $f(x) e^{-x^2/k} \to f(x)$ [uniformly](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJqrxTlyHw4).   Then you can get $\int \lim = \lim \int$ from Riemann integration.

In a Lebesgue theory class, looks like you're integrating with uniform measure on some measurable set.  So perhaps you need [dominated convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Indeed, $f(x) e^{-x^2/k} \to f(x)$ pointwise and $|f(x) e^{-x^2/k}| \leq f(x)$.  Therefore

$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \int f(x) e^{-x^2/k} \, dx \to \int f(x) \, dx$$

So you just need to be sure everything is integrable.